# Open Mapping Theorem doubt regarding existence of open ball

Tags: functional-analysis

[Open Mapping Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU88I.png)

Hello, I was reading the proof of Open Mapping theorem and I don't understand how the parts underlined in red follow.

Specifically how does $B_Y(0,\epsilon)\subset \operatorname{cl} U_1 \implies \exists y_1\in U_1$?

I understand the next part but why is the radius of the open ball $\epsilon/2$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$y$ has been chosen to be a point in $B_Y(0,\epsilon)$ and $B_Y(0,\epsilon)\subset Cl(U_1)$. So $y\in Cl(U_1)$. So for any $r>0$ we can choose  a point $y_1$ in $U_1$ with $\|y-y_1\| <r$. They are taking $r=\epsilon /2$.